# htaccess - How to force http and non-www

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I need to set a htaccess domain configuration where https redirects to http and all www requests to non-www. I thought I could solve it with the following code but it does not work correctly. It only redirects http://www.example.com to http://example.com. https requests end up at e.g. https://example.com with the hint that the connection is insecure.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /

# Redirect HTTPS to HTTP
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# Force non-www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [L,R=301]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Are you running Apache locally, on the same machine as you're running the user-agent accessing https://example.com?

The RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on portion may not work for all networks. Some reverse proxies require RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-SSL} on, for instance.

Comment: I dont run Apache locally. It is a shared host with cPanel but no ssh access. I checked %{HTTPS} on in PHP and it shows https is active while requesting https://example.com. example.com is an example. Real domain is hidden here.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, your shared host proxies all HTTP connections to your site, and forwards them over HTTPS. You never see the connection from the client, only the connection from your shared host proxy. Ask the shared host whether she does or will signal the information you need in HTTP headers such as Forwarded-SSL (or X-Forwarded-SSL).

Comment: I will ask for the information and tell whether it solved the issue.

Comment: The ISP told me the following: "You have no https on your webspace package. You need a SSL to use the port 443."

Comment: But your ISP allows clients to connect to HTTPS://example.com, albeit with an incorrect certificate? I think you need to either obtain technical or sales support from your ISP or just switch providers. I recommend PageKite, because then you're hosting the website on your own computer, in your own house.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com:80/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com:80/$1
```